# How can I add metadata to mp3s, along a timeline to break up one mp3 in subsections?

Tags: metadata, id3, tags

I would like to add metadata to mixtapes or lectures that will show song names as the mix progress as well as being able to skip forward in the mp3 as if it was separate files. I have seen this done in long recordings and it's really useful to be able to get the additional information as well as avoiding fast forwarding.

I assume this would have to be contained in either the id3 or id3v2 standards to work. Id3v2 have a tag called: *"TRCK Track number/Position in set"* which might be useful for this but I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it can be done in the ID3 tag but a CUE file will achieve this.
[Cue sheets on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cue_sheet_(computing))

Comment: Thanks Shevek, cue sheets seems to be what I need. It remains to see how many mp3 players that support them I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do with ID3v2 frames using [this standard](http://id3.org/id3v2-chapters-1.0). [Auphonic](https://auphonic.com/blog/2013/07/03/chapter-marks-and-enhanced-podcasts/), [Forecast](https://overcast.fm/forecast), and [mp3chap](https://github.com/jcs/mp3chap) can add them to existing MP3 files. Apparently some podcast players support the standard, but I've yet to find a desktop app.